# Ansible: Using a dictionary variable within a lookup

Tags: ansible

I am attempting to deploy ssh keys with ansible using a file lookup task that utilizes {{ item.key }} which is simply a username and I am trying to find the appropriate syntax to call for the lookup value.

```
# Deploy Key Task
- name: add user ssh keys
  authorized_key:
    user={{ item.key }}
    key={{ lookup('file', 'files/{{ item.key }}.pub') }}
  with_dict: users
```

Where users is

```
users:
  example:
    state: present
    comment: "Example User"
    shell: "/bin/bash"
    uid: 5001
    gid: 5001
```

From the dictionary, I am wanting to use item.key to populate the user.pub file.

Within the files directory I simply have a file called example.pub with the users public key.

Blockquote

Answer (score 2):

Did some digging and this is what solved it.

```
- name: add user ssh keys
  authorized_key:
    user={{ item.key }}
    key="{{ lookup('file', 'files/'+ item.key +'.pub') }}"
  with_dict: users
```

Note: key="{{ lookup('file', 'files/'+ item.key +'.pub') }}"